# Update manager not showing 14.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I am using ubuntu 12.04.5 . Whenever I am trying to upgrade to 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS, update manager not showing any upgrade. I think 14.04.1 is already relesed over 10 days. But still why I am not notice update manager not showing LTS upgrade?

Comment: Have you not searched Google or this site? This had been asked and answered many times

Comment: `sudo update-manager -d`

Comment: Yes I have searched Google and find answer which is not worked. Several places , it is said that after 14.04.1 release , update manager will show it automatically but after more than 10 days update manager not showing at all. and I don't want to use -d (developement release) Tha's why I asked the question. When update manager will automatically show that options? wheather I will have to change source list or any thing else?

Comment: unfortunately `sudo update-manager -d` is the recommended method for an in-place update.  That being said, an in-place update does not always go well.  You should certainly backup important files, and know what applications you have installed that you will want in 14.04, before starting the update process.

Comment: Those who updated from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS have used update manager or update-manager -d. Whether all of you have found updae manager shows upgrade options 14.04 LTS or have done manually with -d option ? Whether -d option, it will upgrade to 14.04 LTS?

Comment: This might be a strange question but if you go to software update, there is an option that says what type of update the system should look for. There you should select Long Term Support(LTS). I struggled to find 14.04 as an update and the only reason for it was that I didn't select that option.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have told the system to look for Long Term Support Updates.
[image: Under (Software Update) Update Manager>Updates you will have this option]

After you select this try again and let me know if it works.

This guide here shows an upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 but the process was the same for me: http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Upgrade-Ubuntu-12-04-LTS-to-Ubuntu-12-10-303851.shtml

Comment: It is already selected for long term support. Thanks for your reply. Though I have already get notification for upgrade to 14.04 lts and upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

Adding  `-d` is not really an answer for an LTS user.
The  `-d` argument will give a user a dev release; an LTS user will likely want no part of a pre-release product.

Comment: Have you any working link which will solve or any information why update manager is not showing upgrade 14.04 will help